# making a function to do multiplication

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm trying to complete a task it was given at school and I am hitting a wall I have only been learning JavaScript for about 2 days so excuse me if the answer is right in front of my face any and all help is welcome. Below is the instruction given and below the instruction is where I am at with my JavaScript. The problem I am running into is I can't seem to get it to display the cost of the bagels only the amount of bagels themselves I know I am getting close but for the life of me I cannot seem to break through this wall. Thanks in advance and sorry for the blocks of text I am not yet familiar with how to pose questions about these subjects :)

3) calculateBagels
A bagel shop charges 75 cents per bagel for orders of less than a half-dozen bagels and charges 60 cents per bagel for orders of a half-dozen or more bagels. Write a program that requests the number of bagels ordered and displays the total cost.

Test the program for orders of four bagels and a dozen bagels.

```
function bagelcost(number1){
    var result = number1
    if(result >= 6){
        (result * 0.60)
    } else {
        (result * 0.75)
    }
    return result;
}

console.log(bagelcost(100))
```

Comment: Hi Dylan, welcome to SO.  Please try to use the shift key when you type 'I', as SO assumes you may be typing a variable name and does not autocorrect.  Also brevity is cool - apologising once for your inexperience is fine but then move on to the question - people will help you.

Comment: Thanks the SO community rocks so helpful and insightful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to store result while multiplication otherwisw it not retain in result variable which you have return

```js
    function bagelcost(number1){
        var result = number1;
        if(result >= 6){
            result=result * 0.60;
        } else {
            result=result * 0.75;
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    console.log(bagelcost(100));
```

More ever you can directly return result as below

```js
function bagelcost(number1){
       if(number1 >= 6){
            return number1 * 0.60;
        } else {
            return number1 * 0.75;
        }
    }
console.log(bagelcost(200));
```

Comment: To add to this answer you could also just do `return number1* `... the cost. Means you don't have to store the `result`, just return the value.

Comment: @DylanCollis don't forget to set your preferred Answer as "solution".

Comment: Thank @Hydrospanners I have updated my answer as you have suggested different way to return result

Comment: How do i set my prefered answer to solution by clicking the tick next to the users answer i found to be the best solution.?

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the statements `result * 0.60` and `result * 0.75` to the result variable

```
result=result * 0.60;
result=result * 0.75;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly return the calculation. And you can omit the `else` part, because all code after an `if` with `return` is treated as else part. For fixed-point notation use [`Number.toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed).

```js
function getBagelCost(count) {
    if (count < 6) {
        return count * 0.75;
    }
    return count * 0.6;   
}

document.write('$' + getBagelCost(4).toFixed(2) + '<br>');
document.write('$' + getBagelCost(12).toFixed(2) + '<br>');
```

Comment: Thanks ill add this to my javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You were really close.

The key was to save the value. Anything that uses arithmetic like this requires you to capture (assign to a variable, or send as a return value) the result on the left (hence the `a = b + c;` syntax).

If I might make a suggestion, it might make sense if you use more (and more descriptive) words in your functions.
As you learn (and even as you write software as a day job), it's tempting to use arithmetic everywhere, without much explanation, but it becomes easier to forget what's happening.

The same is true for changing the value multiple times. The more times you save a different value saved at the same name, the less you can tell what's happening when.

```
function getCostOfBagels (bagelCount) {
  var discountPrice = 0.60;
  var fullPrice = 0.75;
  var discountVolume = 6;

  var unitPrice;
  if (bagelCount < discountVolume) {
    unitPrice = fullPrice;
  } else {
    unitPrice = discountPrice;
  }

  var totalCost = bagelCount * unitPrice;
  return totalCost;
}
```

Eventually, you might consider refactoring this kind of code, so that this function only does the calculating:

```
var discountPrice = 0.60;
var fullPrice = 0.75;
var discountVolume = 6;


function getBagelPrice (unitCount) {
  var bagelPrice = (unitCount < discountVolume) ? fullPrice : discountPrice;
  return bagelPrice;
}


function getCostOfBagels (bagelCount) {
  var unitPrice = getBagelPrice(bagelCount);
  var totalCost = bagelCount * unitPrice;
  return totalCost;
}

getCostOfBagels(4); // 3.00
getCostOfBagels(12); // 7.20
```